# .htaccess www to non-www while keeping path, ssl, and query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to achieve the following in .htaccess:

1. redirect www to non-www
2. keep the path that has been requested (e.g. `domain.com/path/to/file.php`)
3. keep the query string, if any (e.g. `domain.com/path/to/file.php?key=val&key2=val2`)
4. keep the protocol that has been requested (either http or https)

I tried this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but it doesn't respect http/https, nor does it keep the path that has been requested (e.g. it redirects `https://www.domain.com/path/file.php` to `http://domain.com/file.php`, when it should redirect to `https://domain.com/path/file.php` instead.)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to check if a request is http or https, and redirect to the correct protocol. Right now, you're redirecting everything to `http://`. You can use this condition and grouping:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}:s (on:(s)|off:s)
```

This uses the `%{HTTPS}` variable, which is either "on" or "off", and pairs it with an `s`. Then we match either `on:(s)` or `off:s`. Therefore, if HTTPS is "on", the `(s)` gets grouped and we can backrefernce it using a `%2`, otherwise, if HTTPS is "off", nothing gets grouped and `%2` is blank. We can then use it in your redirect:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}:s (on:(s)|off:s)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http%2://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

As for the second thing about the paths not being preserved, it sounds like your rules are in the directory `/path`, which means it gets stripped off when it gets sent through these rules. You need to move them to your document root. Alternatively, if you *must* have your rules in the `/path` directory, you can use the `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}:s (on:(s)|off:s)
RewriteRule ^ http%2://domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, this looks great. You are correct about the rules being in the /path right now - it's a "dev folder" and I forgot to mention that it will be moved to the root later. I will give your code a try next week but I've marked it as the solution already because it looks really solid. Thanks!